# Scanner input needed twice, when only wanted once

Tags: java

However I'm running into an issue, when trying to input a number, it issues it twice? So I type (x) number and it will space down, and ask for another number? even though I just input one?

(see output code to understand better)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FahrenToCelcius {
    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double celsius, fahrenheit;
        System.out.println("Enter your temperatures");
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] temperatures = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            temperatures[i] = sc.nextInt();

            fahrenheit = sc.nextDouble();
            celsius =(fahrenheit-32)*(0.5556);
            System.out.println("Temperature in Celsius:"+celsius); 

        }    
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Enter your temperatures
100
100
Temperature in Celsius:37.7808
100
100
Temperature in Celsius:37.7808
100
100
Temperature in Celsius:37.7808
```

I only want the user too have to input it once. Help?

Comment: What are you doing with the `temperatures[i]`? you set the value for nothing.

Comment: aren't you reading the scanner twice? once in temperatures[i] = sc.nextInt(); and another in fahrenheit = sc.nextDouble();?

Comment: `//temperatures[i] = sc.nextInt();`  - fixed that for you

Comment: remove the `temperatures[i] = sc.nextInt();` as it is ignored and you will only have to enter it once.  This is where stepping through the code in your debugger should help you.  I suggest you practice on this program before you fix it if you are not familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the array `int[] temperatures` so you could remove the statement that insert in it...

If you really want to keep the value in an array. Simply use a `Double[] temperatures` then read your scanner.

```
...
fahrenheit = sc.nextDouble();
temperatures[i] = fahrenheit;
...
```

**In short, only read the scanner ONCE if you want only one input..**